# How to populate a column of a table from multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql, query

I imported into PostgreSQL a layer which I created an identifier allowing to make a join in order to recover geometries.
These geometries are distributed in several layers and some geometries are present in several layers.

#### Example Data

```
create table  text (text varchar(14), ext int);
insert into text values('BB0010000A0008'); 
insert into text values ('BB0010000A0016'); 
insert into text values ('BB0010000A0018'); 
insert into text values ('BB0010000A0025');
insert into text values ('BB0010000A0022');

select * from text;
```

| text | ext |
| --- | --- |
| BB0010000A0008 | *null* |
| BB0010000A0016 | *null* |
| BB0010000A0018 | *null* |
| BB0010000A0025 | *null* |
| BB0010000A0022 | *null* |

```
create table  geom1 (geom1 varchar (14), ex1 int);
insert into geom1 values ('BB0010000A0008','85203'); 
insert into geom1 values ('BB0010000A0018','89563'); 
select * from geom1;
```

| geom1 | ex1 |
| --- | --- |
| BB0010000A0008 | 85203 |
| BB0010000A0018 | 89563 |

```
create table  geom2 (geom2 varchar (14), ex2 int);
insert into geom2 values ('BB0010000A0008','78456'); 
insert into geom2 values ('BB0010000A0016','74512'); 
select * from geom2;
```

| geom2 | ex2 |
| --- | --- |
| BB0010000A0008 | 78456 |
| BB0010000A0016 | 74512 |

```
create table  geom3 (geom3 varchar (14), ex3 int);
insert into geom3 values ('BB0010000A0019','45126'); 
insert into geom3 values ('BB0010000A0022','56321'); 
select * from geom3;
```

| geom3 | ex3 |
| --- | --- |
| BB0010000A0019 | 45126 |
| BB0010000A0022 | 56321 |

#### The final SELECT Statement

```
SELECT *
FROM text as tt
LEFT JOIN geom1 as t1
ON t1.geom1 = tt.text
LEFT JOIN geom2 as t2
ON t2.geom2 = tt.text
LEFT JOIN geom3 as t3
ON t3.geom3 = tt.text
```

| text | ext | geom1 | ex1 | geom2 | ex2 | geom3 | ex3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BB0010000A0008 | *null* | BB0010000A0008 | 85203 | BB0010000A0008 | 78456 | *null* | *null* |
| BB0010000A0016 | *null* | *null* | *null* | BB0010000A0016 | 74512 | *null* | *null* |
| BB0010000A0018 | *null* | BB0010000A0018 | 89563 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| BB0010000A0022 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | BB0010000A0022 | 56321 |
| BB0010000A0025 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cEWZuyQO)

In the example above I would like to fill the `text` column with the values from `​​geom1`, `geom2` and `geom3`.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output? It's not clear from your description what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dwhitemv  OK, Sorry I'm looking to merge in the "ext" column the info of the "ex1", "ex2" and "ex3 columns. I'm starting to progress but I don't know how to handle duplicates see:  https://dbfiddle.uk/a36NqyaT

Comment: Can you explain what “merge” means for your data? I am not familiar with spatial SQL, sorry. Again, a mock-up of the resultant table would really help.

Comment: @dwhitemv my text array contains ids but without any geometry.
I can search for matching geometries in a layer that contains those geometries.
This layer (in reality these layers) are multiple because it georeferenced layer evolves each year (the geometries evolve and therefore also the identifiers).

at time t: I can find 10 geometries,
at time t-1 , I can find 12 geometries (including 10 already found at time t)

I inserted a link to view things and my query problem : HERE -> https://dbfiddle.uk/a36NqyaT

Comment: @dwhitemv .  I found it ! here : https://dbfiddle.uk/ha12lex-